# Appium setup issues

Tags: android, appium

Trying to setup Appium with Android but keep getting errors. I have an APK manually installed to an actual device. I have followed the instructions on the error message with no luck.

My Desired capabilities are set to:

```
>   "appPackage": "com.XYZ.android",   "appActivity":
> "com.XYZ.android.homepage.HomePageActivity",   "platformName":
> "Android",   "deviceName": "Google Pixel 3a",   "udid": "99NBY3DL9K", 
> "automationName": "UiAutomator2",
```

> > Get this error:

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.XYZ.android.debug' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/Users/pops/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 99NBY3DL9K shell am start -W -n com.XYZ.android.debug/com.XYZ.android.homepage.HomePageActivity -S' exited with code 255'; Stderr: 'Exception occurred while executing 'start': java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.XYZ.android.debug/com.XYZ.android.homepage.HomePageActivity } from null (pid=7171, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10304 at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1043) at
com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.executeRequest(ActivityStarter.java:999) at
com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:669) at
com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAndWait(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1334) at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAndWait(ActivityManagerService.java:3671) at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.runStartActivity(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:539) at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.onCommand(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:186) at android.os.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:98) at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:44) at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onShellCommand(ActivityManagerService.java:10504) at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:929) at
android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:813) at
android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:5053) at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2867) at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1159) at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)'; Code: '255' ...

> 

Comment: I guess HomePageActivity is not the launch activity of the app. Get the correct launch activity name from the app developer and update your desired capabilites.

If you have complete appium log, it also displays what the actual launch activity.

Comment: I got the appactivity running  adb shell dumpsys window windows

Comment: It may run in the background but some other activity is on top of that I believe. That is the reason you are not getting permission to access as launch activity. The log you shared is the complete log? If not complete log will help more to identify the issue.

Comment: Thanks @ShivakrishnaChippa see full appium log

Comment: [info] [35m[HTTP][39m [37m-->[39m [37mDELETE[39m [37m/wd/hub/session/15e6a009-a9de-40a6-a447-0b8848bca803[39m
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [90m{}[39m
[debug] [35m[MJSONWP (15e6a009)][39m Calling AppiumDriver.deleteSession() with args: ["15e6a009-a9de-40a6-a447-0b8848bca803"]

Comment: [debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Event 'quitSessionRequested' logged at 1614020763001 (14:06:03 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time))
[info] [35m[Appium][39m Removing session 15e6a009-a9de-40a6-a447-0b8848bca803 from our master session list
[debug] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Deleting UiAutomator2 session
[debug] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Deleting UiAutomator2 server session
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Matched '/' to command name 'deleteSession'
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Proxying [DELETE /] to [DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8200/

Comment: wd/hub/session/f9c98060-4ef7-497f-87c6-74bb491c29b1] with no body[debug] [35m[Logcat][39m Stopping logcat capture
[debug] [35m[Logcat][39m Logcat already stopped
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Removing forwarded port socket connection: 8200 
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running '/Users/pops/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 99NBY3DL9K forward --remove tcp\:8200'
[warn] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Unable to remove system port forward: Error executing adbExec.

Comment: Original error: 'Command '/Users/pops/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 99NBY3DL9K forward --remove tcp\:8200' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'adb: error: listener 'tcp:8200' not found'; Code: '1'
[info] [35m[UiAutomator2][39m Restoring hidden api policy to the device default configuration
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running '/Users/pops/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 99NBY3DL9K shell 'settings delete global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps;settings delete global

Comment: idden_api_policy_p_apps;settings delete global hidden_api_policy''[debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Event 'quitSessionFinished' logged at 1614020763320 (14:06:03 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time))
[debug] [35m[MJSONWP (15e6a009)][39m Received response: null
[debug] [35m[MJSONWP (15e6a009)][39m But deleting session, so not returning
[debug] [35m[MJSONWP (15e6a009)][39m Responding to client with driver.deleteSession() result: null

Comment: [debug] [35m[MJSONWP (15e6a009)][39m Destroying socket connection
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [37m<-- DELETE /wd/hub/session/15e6a009-a9de-40a6-a447-0b8848bca803 [39m[32m200[39m [90m329 ms - 76[39m
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [90m[39m[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session[39m
[info] [35m[HTTP][39m [90m{"desiredCapabilities":{"appActivity":"com.XYZapp.android.homepage.HomePageActivity","appPackage":"com.XYZapp.android.debug","automationName":"UiAutomator2","deviceName":"Google Pixel

Comment: a","ensureWebviewsHavePages":true,"platformName":"Android","udid":"99NBY3DL9K","newCommandTimeout":0,"connectHardwareKeyboard":true}}[39m
[debug] [35m[MJSONWP][39m Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"appActivity":"com.XYZapp.android.homepage.HomePageActivity","appPackage":"com.XYZapp.android.debug","automationName":"UiAutomator2","deviceName":"Google Pixel

Comment: Lot more in the log but this is the first part

Answer (score 0):

**Enable Developer:**

Navigate to Settings>About and click Build Number multiple time

**Enabled Remote Debugging:**

Goto Settings>System>Developer options>Debugging>USB Debugging and enable it:

[image]

**Connect phone to laptop usb:**

**Now search for device:**

Open cmd and run:

adb devices

You will get prompt in phone for authorization accept it:

[image]

Select always allow from this computer

The output of abd devices command should be like:

[image]

**Accept the prompt and execute the command till you get device instead of unauthorized as output of the command:**

Note:

if you are not getting above prompt then , click revoke ub authotization
Then switch off developer mode using the toogle button and then start the process again from Enable Developer mode in Oneplus:

Read more detailed answer at :

https://praveendavidmathew.medium.com/how-to-connect-oneplus-6-to-appium-studio-72b35609b8f0

Comment: Did you got devices listed when you did adb devices command